# Assign all vendor-prefixed variants to style

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

Modernizr provides a `testAllProps()` method which conveniently tests all the vendor prefixed styles of the one given to see if the style is supported by the currently running browser.

However I have no come to a point where I need to actually assign these properties from javascript because of various reasons that boil down to it being too cumbersome to conditionally link CSS files.

So for instance I could build an array and a routine which assigns each vendor specific style to the style of my target element:

```
['mozTransitionDuration', 'webkitTransitionDuration', 'oTransitionDuration', 'msTransitionDuration', 'transitionDuration'].map(function(s){ element.style.s = "style_setting"; });
```

Well, this will probably generate a bunch of errors because I will try to assign "style_setting" to 4 or 5 undefined values.

Does anybody know anything to make this a bit less painful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to use an existing library that knows all about this stuff:

[Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) will let you assign styles from CSS without vendor-prefixing. There is also a  [jQuery Plugin](https://raw.github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/gh-pages/plugins/prefixfree.jquery.js) for it that will allow you to do the same from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Before setting the value, check whether the property is `undefined`:

```
['mozTransitionDuration', 'webkitTransitionDuration', 'oTransitionDuration', 'msTransitionDuration', 'transitionDuration']
    .map(function(s) {
        if (element.style[s] != undefined) element.style[s] = "style_setting";
    });
```